# Comments on Instagram pages

Tags: comments, instagram

I used to be able to see comments on people's Instagram pages. Do you now have to have an Instagram account to view comments on other people's Instagram?

Comment: No you don't. Clear your browser cache (Ctrl/Cmd + R). They still show when viewing from website

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an Instagram account to view comments. However, you can't view comments on a private IG account unless you create an account and request for that user to let you follow him/her.